# Is $E_n:=\left\{f\in L_1([0,1],m):\int_{[0,1]} |f|^3 dm\leq n \right\}$ absorbing?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-measure

I have to solve an exercise, which I am a little confused about, if I have done correctly.

Let $L_1([0,1],m)$ and $L_3([0,1],m)$ be the Lebesgue space on [0,1]. Recall that $L_3([0,1],m)\subsetneq L_1([0,1],m) $. For $n\geq 1$, define:

$E_n:=\left\{f\in L_1([0,1],m):\int_{[0,1]} |f|^3 dm\leq n \right\}$

Given $n\geq 1$, is the set $E_n\subset L_1([0,1],m) absorbing justify?

To find out if $E_n$ I absorbing, I've started by showing that it is convex, and then I want to show that for all $0\neq f\in L_1([0,1],m)$, there exists $t>0$ such that $t^{-1}f\in E_n$. I've done this by trying to show $\int_{[0,1]}|t^{-1}f|^3 dm\leq n$, and I have done that by:

$\left(\int_{[0,1]}|t^{-1}f|^3 dm\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}=t^{-1} \left(\int_{[0,1]}|f|^3 dm\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\leq t^{-1}n\leq  n$

And then we have that $E_n$ is absorbing.

But I am not sure that it can be done this way

Comment: You know there exists $f\in L^1$ that is not in $L^3.$ How could $tf$ belong to $E_n?$

Comment: I don’t get that. To show that $t^{-1}f\in E_n$, isn’t it enough to show that $\int_{[0,1]} |t^{-1}f|^3 dm\leq n$ for $n\geq 1$

and we have:  $\int_{[0,1]} |t^{-1}f|^3 dm=t^{-3}  \int_{[0,1]} |f|^3 dm\leq t^{-3}n\leq n$ hence $t^{-1}f\in E_n$, or have I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 1):

Take $f(t)=t^{-1/3}$. Then $f\in L^1[0,1]$, since
$$
\|f\|_1=\int_0^1x^{-1/3}\,dx=\frac32.
$$
For any $t>0$,
$$
\int_0^1 |tf|^3\,dm=t^3 \int_0^1\frac 1x\,dx=\infty.
$$
So $E_n$ is not absorbing.